# Throwing exception with coroutine crashes app instead of handling failure

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

From my viewmodel I'm launching a coroutine that could fail and throw an exception, in my coroutine I'm explicitly doing this and instead of catching the exception my app crashes

### ViewModel

```
viewModelScope.launch {
 try {
    repo.getData()
  catch(e: Exception) { print(e) }
}
```

### Repo

```
 suspend fun getData(): Int {
        val productId = getProductId()
        if (productId == 0) throw Exception()
        return productId
    }
```

This crashes my app instead of handling the exception inside the viewmodelScope, I tought that any exception should be propagated to the caller and handled there

Comment: I don't see any reason why this would crash your app. The exception should end up in the catch block and the `launch`ed coroutine should complete normally. Unless there is actually something else crashing your app. Do you see which exactly exception caused the crash?

Comment: Can you check if there is any native library crash in logcat while calling `repo.getData()`?